# regex with optional block of text

Tags: python, regex, parsing

I'm using regex to parse structured text as below, with caret symbol marking what I'm trying to match:

```
block 1
^^^^^^^
    subblock 1.1
        attrib a=a1
    subblock 1.2
        attrib b=b1
                 ^^
block 2
    subblock 2.1
        attrib a=a2
block 3
^^^^^^^
    subblock 3.1
        attrib a=a3
    subblock 3.2
        attrib b=b3
                 ^^
```

A subblock may or may not appear inside a block, e.g.: *subblock 2.2*.

The expected match is *[(block1,b1), (block3,b3)]*.

```
/(capture block#)[\s\S]*?attrib\sb=(capture b#)/gm
```

But this ends up matching *[(block1, b1), (block2, b3)]*.

Where am I doing the regex wrong?

Comment: And you always need the `b` attribute of a subblock? Could you also provide a full example for this statement.... _A subblock may or may not appear inside a block_... what is the expected output there?

Comment: What is *(capture b#)*?

Comment: @AKS Yes always needing the "b" attribute. If the subblock that is supposed to contain this attribute doesn't exist in a particular block, I just want to skip that block and move on to next one. As in the above example, block2 doesn't have subblock2.2, which would have contained attribute "b". So I just discard this block.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew By (capture b#) I mean a regex in the capturing group to pick the value "b#". Simply (\D\d) in the above example. But the values of the attributes could require complex regex per se.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use

```
(?m)(^block\s*\d+).*(?:\n(?!block\s*\d).*)*\battrib\s*b=(\w+)
```

See [the regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/vR7yO4/1)

The regex is based on an unroll the loop technique. Here is an explanation:

- `(?m)` - multiline modifier to make `^` match the beginning of a line
- `(^block\s*\d+)` - match and capture the `block` + optional whitespace(s) + 1+ digits (Group 1)
- `.*` - matches the rest of the *line* (as no DOTALL option should be on)
- `(?:\n(?!block\s*\d).*)*` - match any text after that is not a word `block` followed with optional whitespace(s) followed with a digit (this way, a boundary is set)
- `\battrib\s*b=(\w+)` - match a whole word `attrib` followed with 0+ whitespaces, literal `b=`, and match and capture 1+ alphanumerics or underscore (***note***: this can be adjusted as per your real data) with `(\w+)`

[Python demo](https://ideone.com/j9eb9a):

```
import re
p = re.compile(r'(?m)(^block\s*\d+).*(?:\n(?!block\s*\d).*)*\battrib\s*b=(\w+)')
s = "block 1\n    subblock 1.1\n        attrib a=a1\n    subblock 1.2\n        attrib b=b1\nblock 2\n    subblock 2.1\n        attrib a=a2\nblock 3\n    subblock 3.1\n        attrib a=a3\n    subblock 3.2\n        attrib b=b3"
print(p.findall(s))
```

Comment: Had been hit-&-trying negative lookahead. Thanks for the right syntax!

Comment: Just FYI: the non-unrolled regex version is [`(?m)(^block\s*\d+)(?:(?!\nblock\s*\d)[\s\S])*\battrib\s*b=(\w+)`](https://regex101.com/r/sT2wD1/1) (uses a tempered greedy token). It is a bit more readable, but is not that efficient.

Answer (score 0):

What about this regex? https://regex101.com/r/yZ4fL9/1

```
block (\d).*?attrib b=b(\1)
```